# How to get a random number in a specific range

Tags: java, math, random, int

I know it is asked many times, but all of them are mixed with another questions that make it hard to understand. However I want to use Math.random to get a random number in 0-10.

In fact the random number will be used as index number of a list.

What I have done so far:

```
int random = Math.random(0,9); // Obviously does not work
```

Comment: It's not a BAD question... it's just been asked too many times... mainly because the API is confusing in that Math exposes a partial solution to generating random numbers which noobs (including myself at one time) find and therefore stop looking for a GOOD solution to this problem... so they ask an expert, again, and again, and again. Blame the highly-paid expert API designers, not the noob!

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `Random` object and call [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) to get an `int` between 0 and the inputted number (exclusive).

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int random = rnd.nextInt(11);  // returns range 0-10
```

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Comment: Note: In practice there's no need to get a new instance of Random EVERY time you get a random value... and it can lead to "pointless excessive garbage". Just saying.

Comment: Not just "no need", it's absolutely wrong to do so. If you recreate the object for every call, your numbers won't be random at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Math.random()` Use `Random#nextInt()` instead:

```
int myInt=new Random().nextInt(11);
```

Or, as per comments, use

```
Random r=new Random();
int myInt=r.nextInt(11);
```

and reuse `r` as needed.

Comment: Creating the random object and only getting one number from it won't generate truly random numbers.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker If only one number is being generated it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To get a random item from any java.util.List (using generics) I get:

**WARNING:** The following code is NOT tested.

```
package forums;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public final class ListHelper<T>
{
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public T getRandom(List<T> list) {
        return list.get(RANDOM.nextInt(list.size()));
    }
}
```

... or you may prefer the non-generics solution, which can be static, but requires you to typecast the result of getRandom every time (everywhere) you call it

```
package forums;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public final class Lists
{
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static Object getRandom(List list) {
        return list.get(RANDOM.nextInt(list.size()));
    }
}
```

Cheers. Keith.